# URL Rewriting with .htaccess for HTML pages with query string

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo

I am having some trouble with .htaccess.

I want the URL to be displayed like

> https://www.website.com/deals/11015/dealname

Currently I have the following URL.

> https://www.website.com/single.html?id=11015&name=dealname

Below is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html
RewriteRule . /index.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -d

RewriteRule ^deals/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ single.html?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA]
```

When I try to go on https://www.website.com/deals/11015/dealname, it redirects me to index page. Can someone please help?

Comment: Unable to grasp something here you are doing forbidden redirect and also redirect to index.html as well for same rewrite condition.

Comment: What should I write for the condition?